# Trigger Before Delete Not Firing - MySQL

Tags: mysql

So below is a trigger I'm trying to write before a record is deleted from the 'favorites' table, basically checking to see if a) the attraction I want to delete is even represented in the database and b) if the attraction is even favorited by the user the favorite is tied to. Problem is, for some reason the trigger doesn't seem to be firing (I tried to see if it was firing with the 'insert into reviews' part). Any one see a reason why?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkFavoritesBeforeDeleting 
BEFORE DELETE 
ON favorites
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
DECLARE attExists INT;
DECLARE attNotFavorited INT;

-- insert into review values (5, 1, 'tester');

SELECT count(*) into attExists from attraction where attraction_id = old.attraction_id;
SELECT count(*) into attNotFavorited from favorites where account_id = 
    old.account_id and attraction_id = old.attraction_id;

IF attExists = 0 OR attExists IS NULL then 
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Sorry, but the attraction you wanted to delete does not exist in our database.';
ELSEIF attNotFavorited < 1 then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Sorry, but the favorited attraction you wanted to delete was not even in your list of favorites!';
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So, you are trying to prevent people from deleting favorites that reference non-existent or removed attractions?

Comment: Yes to the first point, to clarify your second I want to prevent people from trying to delete attractions from their favorites that they never even favorited in the first place.

Comment: Technically that is not even possible. You cannot delete a record that does not exist. The DELETE would just (very appropriately) return 0 rows affected. Is there something else you've omitted here from the full trigger that depends on the row existing?

Comment: More accurately, I have the message texts set so that I can have Java pick it up (I'm running this in a Java program); that's the only reason I am setting this up (so I can throw exceptions from MySQL side). Less about preventing the user from doing something and more about the user seeing a message about the current state

Comment: Well.. You will need to find another way. If there is nothing to delete, the trigger won't be fired.